# How to modify this query for pagination fetching?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pagination, sql-server-2008-r2, row-number

This is a pretty complex query so i am having difficulties here. If you help me i appreciate it.

```
select AvgLevel,TotalCount,tblPokedex.PokemonId,Name,Type1,Type2,Hp,tblPokedex.Attack,tblPokedex.Defense,tblPokedex.SpAttack,tblPokedex.SpDefense,tblPokedex.Speed,(Hp+tblPokedex.Attack+tblPokedex.Defense+tblPokedex.SpAttack+tblPokedex.SpDefense+tblPokedex.Speed) as TotalStats 
from tblPokemonStats,tblAvailablePokemons,tblPokedex 
left join tblUsersPokemons on tblPokedex.PokemonId=tblUsersPokemons.PokemonId 
where tblPokemonStats.PokemonId=tblPokedex.PokemonId 
group by tblPokedex.PokemonId,tblPokedex.Name,tblPokedex.Type1,tblPokedex.Type2,tblPokedex.Hp,tblPokedex.Attack,tblPokedex.Defense,tblPokedex.SpAttack,tblPokedex.SpDefense,tblPokedex.Speed,tblPokemonStats.AvgLevel,tblPokemonStats.TotalCount  
order by PokemonId asc
```

Alright so what i want to do is for example select between top 100 and 150

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - tack on a `row_number` column and filter on that:

```
select AvgLevel /*...*/
from (
    select AvgLevel /*...*/, row_number() over (order by PokemonId) rownum 
    from tblPokemonStats,tblAvailablePokemons,tblPokedex 
    left join tblUsersPokemons on tblPokedex.PokemonId=tblUsersPokemons.PokemonId 
    where tblPokemonStats.PokemonId=tblPokedex.PokemonId 
    group by /* etc ... */
) A
where A.rownum > 100 and A.rownum <= 150
```

`row_number` does what it sounds like - it numbers your rows.

Here's another possibility - say you want rows X through Y. You can select the `TOP Y` rows according to your order. Then use that a subquery and select the `TOP Y-X` according to the opposite order.
Assuming X = 100 and Y = 150:

```
select top 50 *
from (
    select top 150 PokemonId
    from tblPokemonStats
    order by PokemonId
) A
order by PokemonId desc
```

As far as performance, I'm not sure which would be better. My gut says that the `ORDER BY` approach is better for pages near the 'front' so to speak, but `row_number()` would be better for later pages (high X and Y). That's just a guess though - run some tests and see what works for you.

Comment: ok this is working but i checked IO count and it is extremely high. i wonder would there be any other better performance solution

Comment: You can't use a variable in a `TOP` expression - you need to replace that with the actual number.

Comment: no i mean that method would not work for pagination in my case :)

Comment: Well, you can use a variable in the `TOP` expression, but then the syntax is slightly different `TOP(@var)`.